# Light switch question

Tags: electrical, switch

Overhead light in attic stopped working - not the bulb.  Checking with multimeter set to ohms, between black & white terminals, display shows a 1 and the light comes on, Switch position doesn't change anything - this happens with the switch in both on and off positions.
Reading voltage - black to white starts at 120V, then decreases to about 94V within 5 or 6 seconds.  Black to ground shows 120V, white to ground shows 0V.  Switch positioned either on or off doesn't change the voltages.
I assume the switch is bad, but I am not an electrician by any measure.  Has anybody ever seen something like this before?

Comment: `display shows a 1 and the light comes on` ... what does that indicate? ... why don't you just say how many ohms you measured?

Comment: There is no reading on the meter other than just a 1.  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: wait a minute! ... did you measure resistance of a live circuit?

Comment: I checked voltage, and didn't understand the changing voltage reading.  I switched to ohms with the switch off, expecting to see infinite resistance with the switch off.  I was pretty surprised when the light over my head came on.

Comment: @ Rob Harrison,  You probably completed the circuit when you switched to ohms.  The switch is bad.

Comment: And the meter may also be, now.

Comment: `light over my head came on` ... I thought that you were talking about a light on the meter

Comment: Well if the house light came on, you had the DMM in amps mode, which won't measure resistance, which is why it showed infinite, and why it acted as a short. Good news is that means the meter is fine. Never leave a meter in amps.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no voltage drop unless loose wire.

The Ohm reading is ONLY for measuring continuity/resistance when all the wires are disconnected. It can not be used on Live wires. It uses small internal battery to send small voltage and current to the loop and reports results. If it shows Infinite, means the circuit is Brocken. If it shows zero, the circuit has no resistance in the path.

Depending on your multimeter type it might have protected it self from you connecting it to 120 Volt wire, or it might have died.

To test the switch, DISCONNECT the wires. Now use multimeter in Ohm position, and observe, showing infinite in switch of position and showing zero in the on position.